# How to replace black values in an array with 0's in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to read in a range of cells and store them in an array then I am going to change all of the blank cells in the array into a 0. However, I keep getting an out of bounds error This is what I have so far.

```
PercentComplete = Range("E3:E149").Value

For i = 1 To 147
    If IsEmpty(PercentComplete(i)) Then
        PercentComplete(i) = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `PercentComplete` is a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way, please. It does not involve any iteration:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, rngBlk As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("E3:E149")) < sh.Range("E3:E149").cells.count Then
     Set rngBlk = sh.Range("E3:E149").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
     rngBlk.Value = 0
 Else
    MsgBox "No empty cells in the range to be processed..."
 End If
```

Or, working on the active sheet, do everything in a shorter variant:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("E3:E149")) < sh.Range("E3:E149").cells.count
    Range("E3:E149").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: Best to account for the possibility of there being no blank cells in the range

Comment: @chris neilsen: Yes, you are right. I will adapt the code to preliminary check that. Thanks! Edited: Adapted it...

Comment: I'm not understanding your check for no blank cells in the range. First, wouldn't the check be on if no special cells that are blank? Looks like you are just checking another column's first 25 rows. Wouldn't an ```On Error``` work best?

Comment: @DanCue  Yes, but I think it is obvious what happened... I  initially posted a code answer without preliminarily checking if there really blank cells exist. After the first comment, I adapted the code, but **the one on my computer, where I tested it on a different range**, and forgot to adapt it after copying here. The more compact second version is adapted. But I will correct the first one now. Thanks!

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for the correction. You don't think the ```On Error``` would be better? I'm seriously asking, not questioning you. I'm trying to understand as I've taken a break from VBA and just got back into some projects that require it.

Comment: @DanCue `On error Resume next` can be also used. But it involves creating and using a variable which to be checked against nothing. The second more compact version do it in one code line, verifying the blank cells existence as you can see. In some other constructions of `SpecialCells` you do not have other choice then handling the error, but when I can avoid that way, I always do it.